# Twitter at underscore (@_)

Tags: twitter

What does the twitter @_ mean/do?  I was under the impression it might be a private message, but I don't know how to search for it to confirm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [somebody's account](http://twitter.com/#!/_).

[image]